# How to setup a custom cron job in opencart?

Tags: cron-task, opencart-3

Can anyone tell me how can I setup a custom `cron job` in *opencart*?

I have Url in below format and when I am manually hit this url it works perfectly now I want to make it dynamic on *cron* schedule basis.

I have setup *cron* job in `https://cron-job.org/en/` using below URL and it works fine but I'm not sure whether it is the right way or not?

```
> http://www.yourstore.com/admin/index_for_cron.php?route=module/modulename/function
```

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

There you'll find instruction:
http://docs.opencart.com/en-gb/extension/cron/

Comment: Useless, it explains how to create a cron job in general, but does not explain how to run it within Opencart environment.

Comment: Use your server cronjob tool. O use free online cronjob tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you able to setup cron tasks on your web-server, you are always can use curl:

```
 curl -s "http://www.yourstore.com/admin/index_for_cron.php?route=module/modulename/function" >/dev/null
```

I'm also managed to run my custom modules for OpenCart3 with command like this:

```
 cd /path/to/your/site && QUERY_STRING="route=module/modulename/function" php -r 'parse_str($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"],$_GET);include "index.php";'
```

(But in this case you need to consider file permissions and run task under appropriate user.)