# Cronjobs on Google Sitemap for Opencart - Php-cli command not found

Tags: php, cron, opencart

Opencart generates its sitemap on the fly and this is a problem in a big catalogs over 10.000 products. So I have modified the function to generate a static sitemap in an XML file.

When I access to my http://localhost/index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap I generate a sitemap-google.xml file without problems and with a unlimited execution time.

I tried to add it in a cron in the development server each 4 hours

```
0 0,4,8,12,16,20 /usr/bin/php /path/to/index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap
```

But I'm receiving a "command not found".

Can I execute on cli the "?params/etc"?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, as the URL parameters are only evaluated this way when calling the script over a server. But a quick solution could be to use `wget`: keep a copy of that sitemap script anywhere under some kind of "secret URL", call it using `wget` and put the result on your disk.

If you cannot use `wget`, you could use a PHP script containing `file_get_contents`. In the same way, it could request the data over a HTTP request and save it in the cached sitemap file.

As a note: if you know which logic should be present to generate that sitemap, you could also write all that logic directly to a PHP script. Running it from shell helps to avoid a blocked server thread, but might be more work

Comment: I can't use wget :( in a http request I go to receive a time out error by the cdn server. But thank you so much.

Comment: @davincy please see my edited answer - maybe that helps?

Comment: Thank you again, I'm a beginner so I will process everything you told me.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62145786/4843247

You can use following command to generate sitemap.xml:

```
cd /PATH_TO_YOUR_WWW_ROOT && QUERY_STRING="route=extension/feed/google_sitemap" php -r 'parse_str($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"],$_GET);include "index.php";' >sitemap.xml.new && mv sitemap.xml.new sitemap.xml
```